# how can I do a following system with just a manytomanyfield?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing a following system for a django project.
models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name='followers_profile')
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name='following_profile')
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And I want to know if I can do this with just a followers field.

Comment: Nop. Both are different (consider the Instagram concept).

Comment: I don't think you can. Both are different concepts and can not be linked. Is there a reason you want to combine them into one ?